# SAS hash merge -- smaller dataset as hash object

Tags: hash, merge, sas, hashtable

I'm using the `%HASHMERGE` macro found at http://www.sascommunity.org/mwiki/images/2/22/Hashmerge.sas and the following example datasets:

```
data working;
    length IID TYPE $12;
    input IID $ TYPE $;
    datalines;
    B   0
    B   0
    A   1
    A   1
    A   1
    C   2
    D   3
    ;
run;

data master;
    length IID FIRST_NAME MIDDLE_NAME LAST_NAME SUFFIX_NAME $12;
    input IID $ FIRST_NAME $ MIDDLE_NAME $ LAST_NAME $ SUFFIX_NAME;
    datalines;
    X   John James Smith Sr
    Z   Sarah Marie Jones .
    Y   Tim William Miller Jr
    C   Nancy Lynn  Brown .
    B   Carol Elizabeth Collins     .
    A   Wayne   Mark    Rooney .
    ;
run;
```

On the `working` dataset, I'm trying to attach the `_NAME` variables from the `master` dataset using this hash merge. The output looks fine and IS the desired output. However, **in my real-life scenario the `master` dataset is too large to fit into a hash object** and the macro keeps placing it as the hash object. I'd ultimately like to flip these two datasets to where the `working` dataset is the hash object, but I cannot get the desired output when I flip the code. Below is the part of the macro that produces the desired output and needs adjusted, but I am unsure how to set this up:

```
data OUTPUT;
    if 0 then set MASTER (keep=IID FIRST_NAME MIDDLE_NAME LAST_NAME SUFFIX_NAME)
    WORKING (keep=IID);
    declare hash h_merge(dataset:"MASTER"); /* I want WORKING to be the hash object since it's smaller! */
    rc=h_merge.DefineKey("IID");
    rc=h_merge.DefineData("FIRST_NAME","MIDDLE_NAME","LAST_NAME","SUFFIX_NAME");
    rc=h_merge.DefineDone();
    do while(not eof);
        set WORKING (keep=IID) end=eof;
        call missing(FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME,SUFFIX_NAME);
        rc=h_merge.find();
        output;
        end;
    drop rc;
    stop;
run;
```

Desired output:

```
IID FIRST_NAME  MIDDLE_NAME  LAST_NAME  SUFFIX_NAME
---------------------------------------------------
B    Carol      Elizabeth    Collins    
B    Carol      Elizabeth    Collins    
A    Wayne      Mark         Rooney 
A    Wayne      Mark         Rooney 
A    Wayne      Mark         Rooney 
C    Nancy      Lynn         Brown  
D
```

Comment: You could filter master dataset with working dataset's IID, then merge filtered master dataset with working dataset, so both datasets are small, it is easy to handle.

Comment: I tried a `SQL left join` filter and it took much longer than reading in the master dataset, sorting, and merging `working(in=a) master` using `if a`.

Comment: Try this to filter: proc sql; create table New_master as select * from master (keep=keep=IID FIRST_NAME MIDDLE_NAME LAST_NAME SUFFIX_NAME) where IID in (select distinct IID from working (keep=IID)); quit;

Answer (score 0):

While it's feasible to do what you say, I doubt you'll get that from a non-purpose-built macro. That's because it's not the normal way to do that; typically you want to keep the main dataset in its form and put the relational dataset in the hash table.  Usually the sizes are reversed of course - the relational table is usually smaller than the main table.

Personally I would not use hash for this particular case.  I'd use a format (or three).  Just as fast as a hash and has less of the size issues (since it doesn't have to fit in memory), though it eventually would slow down (but not break!) due to size.

Format solution:

```
data working;
    length IID TYPE $12;
    input IID $ TYPE $;
    datalines;
    B   0
    B   0
    A   1
    A   1
    A   1
    C   2
    D   3
    ;
run;

data master;
    length IID FIRST_NAME MIDDLE_NAME LAST_NAME SUFFIX_NAME $12;
    input IID $ FIRST_NAME $ MIDDLE_NAME $ LAST_NAME $ SUFFIX_NAME;
    datalines;
    X   John James Smith Sr
    Z   Sarah Marie Jones .
    Y   Tim William Miller Jr
    C   Nancy Lynn  Brown .
    B   Carol Elizabeth Collins     .
    A   Wayne   Mark    Rooney .
    ;
run;

data for_fmt;
  set master;
  retain type 'char';
  length fmtname $32 
         label $255
         start $255
         ;
  start=iid;

  *first;
  label=first_name;
  fmtname='$FIRSTNAMEF';
  output;

  *last;
  label=last_name;
  fmtname='$LASTNAMEF';
  output;

  *middle;
  label=middle_name;
  fmtname='$MIDNAMEF';
  output;

  *suffix;
  label=suffix_name;
  fmtname='$SUFFNAMEF';
  output;

  if _n_=1 then do;
    start=' ';
    label=' ';
    hlo='o';
    fmtname='$FIRSTNAMEF';
    output;
    fmtname='$LASTNAMEF';
    output;
    fmtname='$MIDNAMEF';
    output;
    fmtname='$SUFFNAMEF';
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=for_fmt;
  by fmtname start;
run;

proc format cntlin=for_fmt;
quit;

data want;
  set working;
  first_name = put(iid,$FIRSTNAMEF.);
  last_name  = put(iid,$LASTNAMEF.);
  middle_name = put(iid,$MIDNAMEF.);
  suffix_name = put(iid,$SUFFNAMEF.);

run;
```

That said...

If you do want to do this in a hash table, what you'd need to do is, for each row in MASTER, do a FIND in the working table, then if successful a REPLACE, then FIND_NEXT and REPLACE until that fails.

The problem?  You're doing at least one find *per master row*, which you yourself noted is very large.  If `WORKING` is 100k and `MASTER` is 100M, then you're doing 1000 finds for each match.  That's very expensive, and probably means you're better off with some other solution.

Comment: Thanks for the superb advice as always, @Joe. Makes sense since there is not much documentation on my scenario using a hash table. I'll give the format method a shot! `WORKING` has 22MM rows and `MASTER` has something like 350MM rows -- nasty stuff but has to get done.

Comment: I would definitely not do it with a hash then - find another solution.  Maybe break MASTER up into several sets and hash those.  What size can you fit in a hash?  How much memory do you have?  Get more memory, or smaller datasets - if you can fit 100MM in a hash for example, four hashes might be sufficient, especially if you can intelligently split it (such as an index would) so you can only load 5MM rows from WORKING and the correct 100MM rows from MASTER, instead of 22/100 each time).